# Is there a reference on which Windows SDK contains which platform toolset?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Is there a reference where I can see which platform toolset comes with which Windows SDK?

I'm currently using Visual Studio 2013 with some older projects which have to be build with vc90 and vc100. I already know that the SDK v6.0a contains the vc90 toolset, but cannot find good information about vc100.

Before I download every Windows SDK available or just for future reference:
Is there some sort of table anywhere online where I can see which platform toolset I can get with which package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Wikipedia page that covers the Microsoft Windows SDK has a comprehensive table describing the versions: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows_SDK

Comment: I found it to be clear enough. Perhaps you could elaborate on what you are unclear on.